# A way to differentiate OnDismiss from dialogfragment - Android Studio

Tags: java, android, dialog, fragment

I need some help on somehow differentiate where the ondismiss are coming from.
I'm using two different dialogfragments.

```
DialogClass1 dialog1 = new DialogClass1();
DialogClass2 dialog2 = new DialogClass2();


public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface){

    if(dialogInterface.equals(dialog1){
         //CODE#
    }else if(dialogInterface == dialog2){
         //CODE#
    }

  )
```

Is there a way for this to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If both are of different types check with instanceOf.

```
if(dialogInterface instanceOf DialogInteface1){}
```

Comment: I tried this using both my dialogs but none are working.

Comment: Are the different classes (and dont inherit one another)?

Comment: Yes, they are completely different classes, see below.

Comment: public class DialogClass1 extends DialogFragment implements DialogInterface.OnDismissListener

Comment: public class DialogClass2 extends DialogFragment implements DialogInterface.OnDismissListener